# Delete group in Viber

Tags: viber-messenger

I made a group in Viber by mistake. The other members complain that their phone number is made known to unknown people.

Can I delete the group?

I read that "When all participants leave a group, it will automatically be deleted". How can someone leave a group? There is no choice to "Leave group".

Answer (score 0):

Everyone can leave any group of Viber on their own. Tap the overflow menu on the top-right and select "Leave and Delete".

[image: screen]